# Getting Mime Error when deploying using AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, jsx, config, vite, mime

I am getting a mime error when I have finally successfully deployed my website via Amplify.

error

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

and this is my build

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    build:
      commands: npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: /
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

this is my package json

```
{
  "name": "danise-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.16",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.0.0-alpha.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.5"
  }
}
```

and this is my file tree

project-root
│
├── backend
│   └── (backend files and directories)
│
└── client
├── node_modules
├── src
│   └── (source files for the client)
├── .gitignore
├── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── vite.config.js

this is the repo from GitHub [text](https://github.com/daniserosales/MyProfile)

I have tried

- editing the baseDirectory. I have used:

'/', '/dist', './client

- taken out and put back in the artifacts
- added and removed `cd client` for preBuild commands